# How  is made? How can I use it?

Tags: html, fonts, character, symbols, typography

I'm trying to figure out how can I recreate this symbol ?

I analysed his CSS but I can't see any special font used for this one. Can someone explain what's the trick here?

You can have more information [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%F0%9F%94%9E).

Regards.

Comment: Why do you believe this is _a trick_? Thats just an unicode-character.

Comment: This is a character.  Learn about emoji.

Comment: Why do you downvote me? Isn't it a good question?

Comment: Well, this is [the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) I looked for. Thanks.

Comment: In particular, it is the characer that corresponds to unicode code-point U+0001f51e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this misc symbol,

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>&#128286;</p> 
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is what I was looking for.